# Autohotkey: How to remap CTRL with Alt key and

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to switch the keys

**ALT** and **CTRL**

as well as add

**Alt Down** keys together to behave the same as **Alt Tab**

I have tried with the following script but each works by its own, but not together!

```
; !!!!!!!!!!!! THIS IS WHAT IS ADDED TO THE STANDARD SCRIPT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
LAlt & Down::AltTab

LAlt::LCtrl
```

I am using AutoHotkey v1.1.13.01. It is not the latest because I can't use the latest one for a reason.

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Are you running Windows 8? There are issues with `AltTab` in that OS.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf Windows 7 ..

Comment: Does `LAlt::LCtrl` switch keys? Doesn't it do "on left alt simulate left ctrl pressed as well"? And if it does switch, try `LCtrl & Down::AltTab`.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this

```
LAlt & Down::AltTab

LAlt::LCtrl
LCtrl::LAlt
```

and on my Windows7 system Alt &Ctrl are switched 
and Alt & Down works, too.

Comment: No, it doesn't for me. Are you sure LAlt doesn't stay as alt?